# Refused to execute script, strict MIME type checking is enabled?

Tags: javascript, json

Why am I getting this error in console?

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&q=flower&searchType=image&fileType=jpg&imgSize=small&alt=json'
>   because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and
>   strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You have a `<script>` element that is trying to load some external JavaScript.

The URL you have given it points to a JSON file and not a JavaScript program.

The server is correctly reporting that it is JSON so the browser is aborting with that error message instead of trying to execute the JSON as JavaScript (which would throw an error).

---

Odds are that the underlying reason for this is that you are trying to make an Ajax request, have hit a [cross origin error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com/35553666#35553666) and have tried to fix it by telling jQuery that you are using JSONP. This only works if the URL provides JSONP (which is a different subset of JavaScript), which this one doesn't.

The same URL with the additional query string parameter `callback=the_name_of_your_callback_function` does return JavaScript though.

Comment: i have now given this and it fixes the error <script id="data" type="application/json"

Comment: `type="application/json"` — Now the browser knows it isn't trying to load JavaScript, so it ignores the script element entirely.

Comment: In my case I had a typo in my file path thus I was getting this error.

Answer (score 161):

In my case it was a file not found, I typed the path to the javascript file incorrectly.

Comment: The same. Incorrect path results in some error html-page response, which in turn causes this confusing error message.

Comment: Genious answer. Thank you :)

Comment: The same. Incorrect path typo

Comment: Same here, because of a wrong naming: `foo.js.min` instead of `foo.min.js` 

Comment: I was so sure this wasn't my problem. But it totally was my problem :)

Answer (score 40):

This result is the first that pops-up in google, and is more broad than what's happening here. The following will apply to an **express server**:

**I was trying to access resources from a nested folder.**

Inside `index.html` i had

`<script src="./script.js"></script>`

The static route was mounted at :

`app.use(express.static(__dirname));`

But the `script.js` is located in the **nested folder** as in: `js/myStaticApp/script.js`
[image: refused to execute script, meme type checking is enabled.]
I just changed the static route to:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "js")));`

Now it works :)

Answer (score 17):

Try to use **express.static()** if you are using Node.js.

You simply need to pass the name of the directory where you keep your static assets, to the express.static middleware to start serving the files directly. For example, if you keep your images, CSS, and JavaScript files in a directory named public, you can do as below −

i.e. : **app.use(express.static('public'));**

This approach resolved my issue.

Comment: may not be the correct answer to this specific question but it was the solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I was working on legacy code

and I have this line of code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n.js.php"></script>
```

I was confused about how this supposed to work this code was calling PHP file not js

despite it was working on the live server

but I have this error on the stage sever

and the content type was

```
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

[image]

even it is **text/javascript** in the script tag

and after I added

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

at the beginning for file **i18n.js.php**

the error is fixed

[image]

Comment: Very useful and well-described answer. I had this problem, solved following your advice. Strange enough, I am on a server migration (with identical code but different CentOS, Apache and PHP versions) and only the old server produced this error, even if Chrome Console was showing "text/html" content-type with both servers calls.

Comment: This should be valid answer. Other answers didn't point out the actual fundamental solutions. Maybe original questioner's situation differ, but checking this header should be done first.

Answer (score 8):

After searching for a while I realized that this error in my Windows 10 64 bits was related to JavaScript. In order to see this go to your browser DevTools and confirm that first. In my case it shows an error like "MIME type ('application/javascript') is not executable".

If that is the case I've found a solution. Here's the deal:

1. Borrowing user "ilango100" on https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6098:

> I had the exact same issue a while ago. I think this issue is specific to Windows. It is due to the wrong MIME type being set in Windows registry for javascript files. I solved the issue by editing the Windows registry with correct content type:

> regedit -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes -> You will see lot of folders for each file extension -> Just scroll down to ".js" registry and select it -> On the right, if the "Content Type" value is other than application/javascript, then this is causing the problem. Right click on Content Type and change the value to application/javascript

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNWKa.jpg)

> Try again in the browser."

After that I've realized that the error changes. It doesn't even open automatically in the browser anymore. PGAdmin, however, will be open on the side bar (close to the calendar/clock). By trying to open in the browser directly ("New PGAdmin 4 window...") it doesn't work either.

FINAL SOLUTION: click on "Copy server URL" and paste it on your browser. It worked for me!

EDIT: Copying server URL might not be necessary, as explained by Eric Mutta in the comment below.

Comment: +1 this worked for me. I made the change in the registry to use `application/javascript` for the `.js` extension. Then I closed and reopened pgAdmin and it loaded fine (without copying the server URL). I am running Windows 8.1 and PostgresSQL 13.

Comment: You're right. After trying again it worked fine, without copying the URL.

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally named the js file `.min` instead of `.min.js` ...

Comment: Yeah mine was because the .js file in question did not exist. For some reason I missed copying it over to the folder it was needed in. Jeez def a misleading error IMO.

Answer (score 3):

**Python flask**

On **Windows**, it uses data from the registry, so if the "Content Type" value in HKCR/.js is not set to the proper MIME type it can cause your problem.

Open **regedit** and go to the **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** make sure the key **.js/Content Type** has the value **text/javascript**

```
C:\>reg query HKCR\.js /v "Content Type"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js
    Content Type    REG_SZ    text/javascript
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case (React app), just force cleaning the cache and it worked.

Comment: This was the simple solution

Comment: HOW???           __ __ ___ ___ ___

Comment: @mimic I was meaning, "clearing the browser's cache" (in my case, Google Chrome). 

So, with inspector tool opened, double click on refresh icon and select clear the cache and hard reload

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought you meant the React cache (like git cache) or so.

Comment: but was this was a temporary fix of clearing cache rite

Answer (score 2):

I had my web server returning:

```
Content-Type: application\javascript
```

and couldn't for the life of me figure out what was wrong. Then I realized I had the slash in the wrong direction. It should be:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, while executing my typescript file,
I wrote:

```
<script src="./script.ts"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case Spring Security was looking for authentication before allowing calls to external libraries. I had a folder /dist/.. that I had added to the project, once I added the folder to the ignore list in my WebSecurityConfig class, it worked fine.

`web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/error", "/dist/**");`

Answer (score 1):

## Check for empty `src` in `script` tag.

In my case, i was dynamically populating `src` from script(php in my case), but in a particular case `src` remained empty, which caused this error. Out was something like this:

```
 <script src=""></script> //empty src causes error
```

So instead of empty `src` in `script` tag, I removed the script tag all together.
Something like this:

```
if($src !== ''){
    echo '<script src="'.$src.'"></script>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just use `type`:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="fileType.js"></script>
```

or whichever type you're using, you choose that file type.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, helped in my case. It's probably a cache problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wrote:

```
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script src="/script.js"></script>
```

I was adding a dot at starting of path which was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I have been putting the CSS files in the scripts definition area just above the end of the 
Try to check the files spots within your pages

Answer (score 0):

I am using SpringMVC+tomcat+React

@Anfuca's answer does not work for me(force cleaning the browser's cache)

I used Filter to forward specific url pattern to the React's `index.html`

```
public class FrontFilter extends HttpFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        boolean startsWithApi = requestURI.startsWith("/api/");
        boolean isFrontendUri = requestURI.startsWith("/index.html");

        if (!startsWithApi && !isFrontendUri) {
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(req, res);
        }

        super.doFilter(wrapped, res, chain);
    }
}
```

There is no Spring Security problem bcs my filter executes before Spring Security's

but I still see the same error and find here

Then I realized that I forgot adding one more condition for JS and CSS:

```
boolean startsWithStatic = requestURI.startsWith(contextPath + "/static");
```

Add this to my if condition and problem solved, no more error with MIME type or ('text/html') with js and css

Root cause is that I incorrectly forward JS and CSS type to HTML type

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I realized my app.js was in another folder. I just moved it into that folder where my index.html file is and it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

*Particular case with Cloudfront distribution.*

I was serving a `umd.cjs` file as a CDN, and got the error:

> The resource from “https://your.distribution.com/library.umd.cjs” was blocked due to MIME type (“binary/octet-stream”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

I was saving a `.js` library in a S3 bucket but because of the extension `umd.cjs` the S3 tagged the file as binary, so I had to change the metadata of this file manually and set the content-type to `"application/javascript"`

If you have a particular case as me, try to find any useful or extra metadata that you can configure in your service providers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was no code change nor deployment and it was actually accessible a day before yet im seeing this issue.

I resolved this by clearing my browser data for the past 24hours.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a `npm run build` I tried to open the `Index.html` file locally and got the error in title. I tried using Live Server and found the paths to resources were incorrect.

To work around this I used http-server **to run the app locally**:

Install http-server globally if you haven't already:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Navigate to your build folder:

```
cd your/build/folder
```

Start the server:

```
http-server
```

It will prompt you to open localhost:8080

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had a symlink for the 404'd file and my Tomcat was not configured to allow symlinks.

I know that it is not likely to be the cause for most people, but if you are desperate, check this possibility just in case.

Answer (score -1):

Add the code snippet as shown below to the entry html. i.e "index.html" in reactjs

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: I would appreciate very much an explanation on why is this useful.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a route on express such as:

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

Try to change it for something more specific:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

For example.

Or else you just might find yourself recursively serving the same HTML template over and over...

Answer (score -1):

In Angular Development try this
[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my situation in was  because its MIME type ('application/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled was error on GoDaddy using Bridge Theme with  QI Slider loading Bootstrap: carousel.js v3.0.0 and was missing transitions.js. Add CDN from cloudflare
transition.js v3.2.0. CDN is here  https://www.cdnpkg.com/twitter-bootstrap/file/transition.js/

Answer (score -1):

In my case that script file has wrong suffix name.
I used `script.min.js` instead of `script.js.min`

Answer (score -2):

By adding type="text/javascript" to the script tag worked to me

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n.js.php"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I hade same problem then i fixed like this

```
change "text/javascript"
```

to

```
type="application/json"
```

Comment: That stops the browser making the request for the URL in the first place and makes the `script` element's presence in the document entirely pointless.

Answer (score -15):

I solved my problem by adding just ${pageContext.request.contextPath} to my jsp path .
in stead of :

```
 <script    src="static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

I set :

```
 <script    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```