# Refused to execute script from 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/mraid.js' because its MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: mime, adsense

I get these error types in google chrome for adsense ads.

"Refused to execute script from 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/mraid.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

At the same time our adsense ctr dropped very significantly while we moved to a new server. Especially our text ads ctr dropped. I wonder if its related to those error codes.

www.pricepony.com.my/blog/nokia-maze-monster-8gb-ram-dual-24mp-camera-for-only/?utm-source=9f67864789eg[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdXA3.png)

our developers are convinced the issue is caused from google site and not our server site. Is this our issue or does it come from google code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refused to execute script, strict MIME type checking is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574159/refused-to-execute-script-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabled)

Comment: Most likely you are using a `<script>` tag without the correct `type` attribute or, in some cases, you are pointing to the wrong location. Both issues are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574159/refused-to-execute-script-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabled

Comment: do you think this could cause the impact on ad ctr? somehow my developers cant replicate the error

Comment: it's likely. I'm not really familiar with adsense but you're definititely having an issue there. The script you are pointing to does in fact throw a 404 error, so you should focus on that first

Comment: thank you. my dev is saying its google not us, because it points to 404. But i really hope we can fix it on our end. google is taking 2 weeks already for this "bug"

Answer (score 0):

https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/mraid.js
Returns a 404 error. No wonder its mime type is HTML.