# "ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" and "its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled" in console

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new at web development and in the phase where you do as many projects as you can for practice. I have a simple website for my profile and two script tags at the bottom of my index page right before the closing body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

They are kept in a folder called "js" and have the .js type. The app.js has my js for a contact form and the scroll.js is empty for now.

I get a bunch of errors in the console in Chrome:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/js/scroll.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:127 GET http://localhost:3000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:126 GET http://localhost:3000/js/scroll.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
:3000/#about:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/js/scroll.js' 
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is 
enabled.
localhost/:127 GET http://localhost:3000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
:3000/#about:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/js/app.js' because 
its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I would really appreciate any help. This is also my first time asking a question here so thanks for your patience.

UPDATE:
Thank you ll for your help - I learned a lot. I'm having a related issue now. I moved app.js and scroll.js to the correct folder and got it, however now everyday I try to run the server, it seems to be going to the wrong directory.

ex:Failed to lookup view "contact" in views directory "C:\Users\eh653\desktop\profile\public" then the next day Failed to lookup view "contact" in views directory "C:\Users\eh653\desktop\profile\public\views".

Here is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('contact');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
const output = `
<p>You have a new contact request</p>
<h3>Contact Details</h3>
<ul>  
  <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
  <li>Company: ${req.body.company}</li>
  <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
  <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
</ul>
<h3>Message</h3>
<p>${req.body.message}</p>
```

`;

```
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mail.host.com', 
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: 'example@example.com', // generated ethereal user
        pass: 'password'  // generated ethereal password
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Emily Hickey" <info@emilyrhickey.com>', // sender address
    to: 'emilyrhickey89@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Node Contact Request', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
    html: output // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

    res.render('contact', { msg: 'Email has been sent' });
});
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

I'm not sure why it keeps changing each day to another folder. Again, thanks for any help.

Comment: If you try to open `http://localhost:3000/js/app.js` in your browser directly, does it load? Is that the right path relative to the root that's being served on `localhost:3000` by your dev web server?

Comment: no it doesn't load - I'm guessing it's something simple newbie would miss.

Comment: See the link below, this should help with your issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574159/refused-to-execute-script-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabled

Comment: @EmilyHickey OK, so you can narrow down your problem: ignore the "strict MIME type checking" errors, the only part you need to care about is `http://localhost:3000/js/scroll.js ... 404 (Not Found)` You need to find what the correct URL is for `scroll.js` to be found, or where to put it so that it will be found at that URL. We don't have enough information to tell you that, so you'll have to do some more digging and [edit] your question with what you find out - Where does the web server expect to find files for `localhost:3000`? Where are your JS files relative to that?