# MIME type issue with angular-i18n

Tags: angularjs, mime

I have installed angular-18n to my project, and when I include the script :

`<script src="/node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_fr.js"></script>`

I'm getting this error :

> Refused to execute script from
>
> 'http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_fr.js'
>   because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and
>   strict MIME type checking is enabled.

How to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refused to execute script, strict MIME type checking is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574159/refused-to-execute-script-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabled)

Comment: Which web server are you using?