# GeoJSON file: Refused to execute script from because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geojson, mime-types

My web application has a folder named "data" which has .geojson files. When I tried to access my website from Chrome I can see all .geojson files loaded with "200 OK response" Please find below screenshot.

[image]

But when I see console logs I am getting "Refused to execute script from because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

[image]

I have the following code snippet in my HTML file.

[image]

Same code working fine in Internet Explorer. I am able to use all .geojson files data from my JavaScript code. Can someone guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have tested the code snippet on my side, it will show 404 error in IE and Chrome browser, but if  I use the following code `<script src="https://embed.github.com/view/geojson/benbalter/dc-wifi-social/master/bars.geojson"></script>`, it works well, for more detail information, you could check [this article](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/mapping-geojson-files-on-github). Besides, here is an thread related to [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574159/refused-to-execute-script-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabled), you could check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoJSON is not a script; it's data, and the type `text/javascript` is the wrong MIME type for GeoJSON files. If you're loading GeoJSON from other JavaScript code, you should do so in another way rather than using `<script>` tags in HTML, perhaps through XMLHttpRequest.

(From comment of mine on Jan. 6, 2020): In any case, Internet Explorer has by now become a legacy product, now that Microsoft has focused its Web browser efforts on Chromium, which is the browser rendering engine behind Google Chrome and recent versions of the Microsoft Edge browser.