# Bootstrap upgrade from 3.4 to 5.3 in .Net project

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, .net, bootstrap-5

I have Website poject created .Net Framework 4.7.2
Currently I am using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) version 3.4.1

Bootstrap 3.4 is in end-of-life state. Therefore I need to update to the latest version 5.3

When I replaced the new version files bootstrapfiles in the project. The version 3.4 is quite old. I am getting different errors in console, one of them is
*Index:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:xx/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled*

I want to ask, are there any specific steps(or commands) to follow while updating Bootstrap in the applications?

Comment: See: [Refused to execute script, strict MIME type checking is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40574159/22152755)

Comment: if you try opening `https://localhost:xx/bootstrap.bundle.min.js` in your browser, is it accessible?

Comment: In addition to upgrading bootstrap, did you upgrade jQuery? Later versions of bootstrap require later versions of jQuery. And also keep in mind that later versions of bootstrap removed the glyph-icons, and support for them. That means you have to either get some css that includes (supports) the glyph-icons. We decided that was too messy, and thus we changed over to font-awesome, but that did require re-working of any glyph-icons being used for things like buttons etc. Turned out this "simple" change resulted in quite a bit of work. However, for starters, I would upgrade your jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be a very long time for you, because as far as I know, it is not possible to solve this in any short way, you just need to upload your project to Github and save a copy, then delete Bootstrap and download a new one, then you have to change the errors one by one according to the new Bootstrap library.

Comment: Well, I kind of agree here! I updated bootstrap for one site, and we still find some css and  errors cropping up even several months later. The other issue was that since or around bootstrap 4.x, they dumped (removed) support for the glyph-icons, and thus we had to re-work a  lot of icons. We in fact dumped glyph-icons (since they are no longer included with bootstrap, and went with font awesome. So, what should have bene a simple and easy upgrade of bootstrap? Well, it was not. And of course, while one is at this, upgrading jQuery version is quite much required. So, a lot of work!